# C# process with arguments not working

Tags: c#

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.FileName = "convert.exe";
psi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\Der\Downloads\Wunderground_API_Test\Wunderground_API_Test\Wunderground_API_Test\";
psi.Arguments = " icone.gif -fuzz 10% -transparent white icone.ico";
Process.Start(psi);
```

If I try to run this nothing happens but if go to that path and type `convert.exe icone.gif -fuzz10% -transparent10% white icone.ico` it works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is "convert.exe" relative to your executable? Its likely just not finding the file. Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: convert.exe is in the system path

Comment: Can you capture the output as [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15032982/578411) and let us know if that shows anything?

Comment: it shows Invalid parameter - -fuzz

Comment: Well, there is your problem...

Comment: but if I type the same comand in the command promp it works

Comment: It might be the extra space in the arguments.

Comment: I removed the space and nothing changed and also if I try icone.gif icone.ico the error changes to invalid parameter icone.ico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because C# passes **StartInfo** parameters as Unicode and your program **"convert.exe"** does not handle intepretting the Unicode arguments.  While calling it through a batch file the way you are doing it does not pass the parameters as Unicode.

Below link looks like addresses your issue. With code examples.

[Application started by Process.Start() isn't getting arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000793/application-started-by-process-start-isnt-getting-arguments/24147111#24147111)

Answer (score 2):

I gave up and did a bat file and it works.

```
        var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\LL\Downloads\Wunderground_API_Test\Wunderground_API_Test\Wunderground_API_Test\icone.bat";
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\LL\Downloads\Wunderground_API_Test\Wunderground_API_Test\Wunderground_API_Test\";
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 1):

So, trying this out on my machine in LINQPad, I think it might be a misunderstanding of a working directory.  The working directory is not the location of the file, it's where the file should think it's being run from.  Try removing that line and specifying the complete path in FileName.  That worked for me.

Comment: The error the OP gets is from the windows convert.exe tool that `Converts a FAT volume to NTFS.`....