# cmd converting language other than English to junk

Tags: c#, cmd

I'm making a uiautomator based application where the app touches the objects based on text. 
I've written the uiautomator methods in Java and have made a C# app which asks the used which text to touch. I'm using cmd/adb to execute the uiautomator commands.

The problem comes when I change the phone language to something other than English. Cmd/adb replaces the text (in other language) with ???. It passes the same to uiautomator. 
Is there a way I can make cmd understand the other language?

C# code

```
            Process procToExecute = new Process();
            procToExecute.StartInfo.FileName = "adb.exe";                
            procToExecute.StartInfo.Arguments = strCommand;                 
            procToExecute.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            procToExecute.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procToExecute.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procToExecute.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
            procToExecute.Start();
            procToExecute.WaitForExit();
```

where strCommand looks like this for other languages

```
adb shell uiautomator runtest UiAutomatorTest.jar -c com.lge.uiautomatorTest.UiAutomatorClass#UiEnterText -e edit संदेश%दर्ज%करें -e text को
```

and it shows like this on cmd

```
adb shell uiautomator runtest UiAutomatorTest.jar -c com.lge.uiautomatorTest.UiAutomatorClass#UiEnterText -e edit ?????%????%???? -e text ??
```

Comment: take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2628727/1805974 it might just be that the commandline cannot show the characters, however the  problem might be the java program, that  needs to use utf16 for reading arguments

Comment: This is not aboput languages but about fonts and codepages!

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen Nope.. If I hard code the value in my java file, it works fine.. So I'm not sure if the problem is with the Java file.