# Problems restoring a database in PostgreSQL with C# WPF

Tags: c#, postgresql

How can I create a restore using PostgreSql 9.4 and C #? I'm using this method in question, but when I run the process it does not work! whats wrong?

```
private void btnRestore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (clsB.ConectaBanco())
    {
        //Executo a seguinte função para limpar a base de dados, para poder dar o restore.
        clsB.ExecutarSQL("drop schema public cascade; create schema public;");

        //E executo o seguinte processo
        string Comando = CaminhoPg + @"psql -U postgres -d restore2 -f C:\Users\bruhh\Desktop\Backup\back.backup";

        Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = CaminhoPg + @"psql" ;
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-U postgres -d restore2 -f C:\Users\bruhh\Desktop\Backup\back.backup";

        p.Start();

        p.WaitForExit();
        p.Close();

        MessageBox.Show(Comando);
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error loading database settings");
}
```

The result of the various Comando is

```
C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.4\\bin\\psql -U postgres -d restore2 -f C:\\Users\\bruhh\\Desktop\\Backup\\back.backup
```

The process even executes but in all the lines "invalid command" appears. What would it take to make this code work?

How the process gets when it runs
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AUvL.png

---

Method used to perform Backup

```
public string BackupDatabase(string CaminhoNome)
{
    string server = clsConfigBanco.SERVERNAME;
    string port = clsConfigBanco.PORT;
    string user = clsConfigBanco.USERNAME;
    string password = clsConfigBanco.PASSWORD;
    string dbname = clsConfigBanco.DATABASENAME;
    string backupCommandDir = @"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin";
    try
    {
       Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PGPASSWORD", password);

       string backupFile = CaminhoNome;
       string BackupString = "-ibv -Z3 -f \"" + backupFile + "\" " +
                "-Fc -h " + server + " -U " + user + " -p " + port + " " + dbname;

       Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
       p.StartInfo.FileName = CaminhoPg + "\\pg_dump.exe";
       p.StartInfo.Arguments = BackupString;

       p.Start();

       p.WaitForExit();
       p.Close();

       return backupFile;
   }
   catch
   {
      return "";
    }
 }
```

Apparently the backup is correct because when I generate the backup I can give restore by PostgreSql9.4 but I can not with the application. my backup file also gets some strange characters is this normal?
[Here is a system-generated backup](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DC54A3B20D43A7B3!67578&authkey=!ANwGmLGoY7jzGko)

How do I get my restore to work?

Comment: What does WPF have to do with this?

Comment: looks like psql can't handle unicode you're giving it. Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627891/does-process-startinfo-arguments-support-a-utf-8-string